# Why can't I log this array of td elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a connect four game and needed to log the td or table cell that gets clicked, but I'm getting something else in the console? Any Ideas How to do this? I'm trying to do it by selecting all the table cells 
`const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');`

then adding an event to each cell
`for(let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        //add event listener to each cell
        cells[i].addEventListener('click', placeChip(this));`

then the function looks like this

`function placeChip(cell) {
    console.log(cell);
}`

```js
const board = document.querySelector('table');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

//select and darken chosen column
board.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
 //determine which column is being hovered over and store in var
 let column = e.target.className;

 //loop through all table cells
 for(let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  //add event listener to each cell
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', placeChip(this));
  //check to see if table cells class matches column
  if(cells[i].className === column) {
   //change the background color of the matched cells
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#0000cc';
  } else {
   //change unmatched cells to the default color
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
 }
})

function placeChip(cell) {
 console.log(cell);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-end;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

table {
 background-color: #0000cc;
}

td {
 border: 3px solid #0000cc;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="board-wrapper">
  <table>
   <tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-3">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-4">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-5">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row-6">
    <td class="column-1"></td>
    <td class="column-2"></td>
    <td class="column-3"></td>
    <td class="column-4"></td>
    <td class="column-5"></td>
    <td class="column-6"></td>
    <td class="column-7"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With `cells[i].addEventListener('click', placeChip(this));` you're invoking the function immediately, not passing it to `addEventListener`, use `.bind` or a higher-order function

Comment: And you're calling `cells[i].addEventListener` *every time* you mouse over the board.

Comment: You should not pass "this" as param in your addEvent listener statement. Try these changes which will fix your problem.
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', placeChip);      function placeChip() { 
 console.log(this) };   here is jsfidde  https://jsfiddle.net/0yjezurp/

Comment: @CertainPerformance How am I invoking the function immediately? I thought it can only be invoked when clicked as that is what the event is listening for. Also I don't know what the .bind function is or what its used for

Comment: You invoked the function and then passed it to `addEventListener`, so the function gets invoked immediately, not on click.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I still don't undertsand how it's invoked immediately? The placeChip function is only invoked when a cell is clicked. The only other function is the one from the 'mouseover' event. which adds the event listener to every cell when the mouse is hovered over the board. Can you be more specific I'm a newbie

Comment: Your code is `cells[i].addEventListener('click', placeChip(this));` - whenever the board is moused over, `placeChip(this)` will be called for *every* cell, passing the result as the handler to `addEventListener`. Instead, don't invoke the function.